# How to get one individual digit from a number that has more than one digit in it

Tags: c++

So I have a four digit number that is player-input in a simple puzzle I am making, I want to be able to check each digit, say I want to check the second digit to the right, if the number happens to be 4601 then of course it will be 6 but is their a faster way other than testing every single four digit number?
I found a few results with search but they didn't help, they just confused me more, please phrase any answers so anyone can understand them. 
Also i am using c++.

Comment: `say I want to check the second digit to the right, if the number happens to be 4601 then of course it will be 2 ` how will this be `2`?

Comment: How is second digit to the right of 4601 two?

Comment: If you read the input as a string, you can just check the second character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve the second most significant (base ten) digit from an arbitrary integer `i` you could do:

```
while (i >= 100)
    i /= 10;
return i % 10;
```

Of course, this assumes the number greater than or equal to 10 to begin with. If you need to preserve the number, then you will (obviously) want to be operating on a copy.

## EDIT:

One could define a function for extracting an arbitrary digit using either arithmetic or string operations.

### Arithmetic solution:

```
int extractDigit(size_t digit, int n) {
    int mask = 1;
    while ( digit --> 0 )
        mask *= 10;
    if (n < mask / 10) { // insufficient digits
        return -1; // or some other appropriate error handling.
    while ( n >= mask )
        n /= mask;
    return n % 10;
}
```

### String solution:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

int extractDigit(size_t digit, int n) {
    string result = static_cast<stringstream&>(stringstream() << n).str();
    if (result.size() < digit) {
        return -1;
    }
    return result[digit-1] - '0';
}
```

Both of these solutions implicitly assume that `n` will be non-negative. You could enforce this pre-condition by using an unsigned data type if you need to. Also, both of these functions are defining the digit positions such that the most significant is in position 1, and the positions increase to the right.

Comment: Ok, after deciding to use the / thing, as it doesn't require me to learn new array stuff that kinda confuses me... ...how to i get rid of numbers to the left of the least significant digit? I finally remembered that dividing ignores remainders so dividing a three digit number by 100 will get it down to the most significant digit, however if i want the least significant digit i can't figure that out, i need to get rid of the digits off to the left of it, how would i do this?

Comment: That's where `% 10` comes in. Roughly, that translates to `the remainder after dividing by 10` or in other words, the least significant digit.

Comment: While your edit makes my brain hurt I now feel stupid, thanks for explaining/refreshing my memory on the %, I know what it did but didn't think of it that way... ...(just to make sure) So the following code should select the digit that is corresponding with the int's name:   int onev2 = guess; int twov2 = guess; int threev2 = guess; int fourv2 = guess;
                
                onev2 = onev2 % 10;
                
                twov2 = twov2/10; twov2 = twov2 % 10;
                
                threev2 = threev2/100; threev2 = threev2 % 10;
  
                fourv2 = fourv2/1000;

Answer (score 1):

I am not guessing anything about what you going to do after you have the digit.But if its only the digit you want to have then you could use below:

```
int a=1234;
char b[4];
sprintf(b,"%d",a);
char c=b[1];
```

Now `c` has the second digit of your 4 digit number.
like wise you can access all the digits using the index to character array `b`

for a c++ equivalent pls see below:

```
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << age;
```

Now `out.str()[1]` will show the second digit.

Comment: As the OP specified they're using c++, there are better ways to do this solution than a char array.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the number as an `int` and convert it to a `char` array and check each char as a digit

Example:

```
char digits[5];
int number;
//Read number in
scanf("%d",&number);
//Make sure it's 4 digits
number%=10000;
//Convert it to a char array
sprintf(digits,"%d",number)

if(digits[1]=='6')
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was a stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out Vikdor.

Comment: James: That's exactly why i get more confused... people throwing random things out without explaining them.                                    PSIAlt: Nothing, i couldn't come up with any idea's,                     graphics: i will looks up char arrays to see if i can figure anything out.                                                           off-topic: How do you change your name, i feel like a clone with this name user xxyyxxyy.

Comment: So i am basically looking for a way to divide by 100 and then remove any decimals, i'm still no c++ math genius or anything...              jpm: While i kinda understand what you are gonna say its gonna take me a while... thanks for a reply everyone.

Comment: itoa is a non standard function. It is better to use some thing like sprintf() which is guaranteed to be portable. Though converting to string, doing manipulation and then may be back to integer is a terrible waste, and doing division with taking mod is a better idea,as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: I already pointed this out on another answer, but OP is using c++. Why are we giving answers using char arrays and c string functions?

Comment: For the string implementation, it works and uses less code (switched to sprintf). Also faster & more practical than the function you wrote if you want to be examining each digit like OP. In either case an array is best - constant time access. I could switch my answer to have the array subtract '0' from each element but it's moot by now.