# C++: getting the front digit of a 2 digit number

Tags: c++, numbers, histogram

I am currently working on a histogram and I'm new to C++, so I don't know if there is an easy way of doing this, can anyone please help?

Numbers are always between -1 and 99.
I want to return the first digit.
I know it is possible to return the last digit using %, but can't find a way to return the first one.

```
Examples:
98 --> 9
87 --> 8
24 --> 2
10 --> 1
==For anything under 9 I would like to return a 0==
9  --> 0
5  --> 0
0  --> 0
-1 --> 0
```

Comment: So it seems "gimme teh codez" questions are OK on SO after all...

Comment: @juanchopanza: Surely questions about specific programming problems have always been OK? Or should SO be reduced to nothing other than "why are my codez broken" or "pleeze read the C++ standard for me"? I for one would find that rather boring.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'd expect at least some reasoning on ways this could be done and why they failed / what went wrong. That also applies to the categories you mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get one individual digit from a number that has more than one digit in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338607/how-to-get-one-individual-digit-from-a-number-that-has-more-than-one-digit-in-it)

Answer (score 5):

The general way to get the second digit (even for cases when numbers can be greater than 99) is

`n / 10 % 10`

Note that for -11 it will return -1. If you want 1, then do `(n >= 0 ? n : -n) / 10 % 10`

Answer (score 3):

Just return the number divided by 10 i.e.

```
int get_digit_2nd(int number)
{
    if(number <= 0)
        return 0; 
    return number / 10 ; // since your number is below 100. 
}
```

Comment: My mistake. Edit made. There is no division by 0. :)

Comment: Thank you! I did not think of this, I forgot that int/int = int and never float.

Comment: Note that this will not work for numbers >= 100. Refer to Ishamael's answer to understand the general method. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since numbers always smaller than 100,

```
n/10;
```

would be enough.

But `n` could be -1, so

```
answer = n >= 0 ? n/10 : -1
```

Comment: The desired answer for -1 is 0, and in C++ (-1)/10 happens to be zero, so no need for special casing it.